# Detect rotation in text

Tags: php, rotation, gd

I've got an image which has a text on it, for example "test". The text on this image is randomly rotated by an angle. How can I detect, using the GD how much it's rotated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not at all easy. There is no builtin method in GD to do this, you have to implement some algorithm for this.

One algorithm could try to find the smallest rectangle with all text in it and determine the rotation of that rectangle.

Comment: I like the idea conceptually, but consider "pest" the smallest bounding box that would contain it would be slanted, due to the descender on the "p" and the ascender on the "T"

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'm having a hard time writing code for this, anybody give me a hand?

Comment: pest, considered: http://screencast.com/t/TZjiJ7dw & http://screencast.com/t/gxaGHicg